# how to render an element n number of times in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

given a count, i am trying to render a button and in the text show number.

for example, if count is 5, then I am trying to make `<Button>1</Button>` to `<Button>5</Button>`.

How can I do this in react?

Comment: Show some real code please...

Comment: Do you want just the count displayed in the button? Or do you want there to be 1 button when count is 1 and 5 buttons when count is 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show `state` inside `button`., and `onClick` event set new state

```js
var Counter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { counter: 0 };
  },
   
  handleClick: function () {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={ this.handleClick }>{ this.state.counter }</button>
    </div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```